# How to convert std::string to upper case?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to convert a `std::string` to uppercase. I am aware of the function `toupper()`, however in the past I have had issues with this function and it is hardly ideal anyway as use with a string would require iterating over each character.

Is there an alternative which works in correct manner of the time?

Comment: How could converting a sequence of characters to uppercase possibly not involve iterating over those characters?

Comment: And why would the functionality NOT ALREADY BE THERE instead of having to recreate the wheel all the time.  ISNUMERIC and REPLACE being two other recent examples I've run into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::toupper` has several overloads

- `template <class charT> charT toupper(charT, const locale&)`
- `int toupper(int ch)`

So taking its address might be complicated. (and it is not even allowed).

You might use lambda to let compiler found the right overload:

(In addition, as `char` might be signed or not, and `toupper` expects `unsigned char` value (or EOF))

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
               [](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); });
```

Comment: _"as use with a string would require iterating over each character."_ Same same here, with cream, candy and syrup.

Comment: @user9212993 well BY DEFINTION you have to iterate over each character to make sure you have converted them all. You are kinda asking for the impossible otherwise.